# Why can't I write from table specified in FOR EACH SMO Enumerator to Spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have the FOR EACH SMO Enumerator working. It is (presumably) looping through each table in my data base and putting the table name into my variable User::TableName.

Within the loop I have a Data Flow Control with my date base and the table pointed to by the TableName variable

I have as my destination an Excel Destination. The arrow between the OLEDB Source and the Excel Destination has all the right metadata.I have the connection Manager of the Excel Destination pointing to a valid output spreadsheet. I have the Connect String Property of the Excel spreadsheet pointed to by the User::TableName variable.

SSIS does not like this and I can't figure out why.If I Edit the Destination Connection and try to go to the Mappings or Error Output tabs I get the following error message:

> "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
>   Error at Package2[Connection Manager "Destination ExcelConnection Manager"]: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form x = y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination[2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code 0x8004005.
>
> Error ata Data Flow Task [Excel Destination[2]]: Opening a rowset for "[dbo.Template]" failed. Check that the object exists in the database."

[dbo],[template] exists in the database. I created that as a clone of one of the other tables (all of which are the same) so that the Excel Destination would have a table with metadata. I also initialized my TableName variable to that.

Can anybody tell me what IU have to do to my Data Flow task to make it do what I want, loop through each table in the data base and have it write a spreadsheet for each table.

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: Please share your connection string by replacing sensitive information in it.

Comment: Source Connection From Properties is  - Data Source=servername.domainname.com;Initial Catalog=CompromisedCards;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;  but OLE DB Source Editor Says Table name or view name from variable and Variable Name = User::TableName

Comment: Destination Cinnection String says

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Compromised Cards\Template.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

I want to replace Template.xlsx with Table1.xlsx, Table2.xlsx, etc., with what is contained in my variable User:TableName as the FOR EACH SMO Enumerator loops through the tables and puts a new name in User::TableName